# Problem with socket when using it in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, router

I have a problem with the socket in my program. export the "io" connection and although I can broadcast from any part of the normal program (just by referring to "io"), I cannot use "socket" and broadcast with it unless it is within the same connection of "io." I would like to know how to use socket from any other part of the program, with functions such as "socket.emit ()" or "socket.broadcast.emit" etc. Or how to call this one.

This is my index.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const restApi = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const server = require('http').createServer(restApi);
const rutas = require('./src/routes/Routes.js');
const io = require('./src/socket/SocketManager.js');
io.attach(server);

restApi.use(express.json());
restApi.use(express.static('public'));
restApi.use(cors());
restApi.options('*', cors());

server.listen(4040, () => console.log('Listening server in port 4040'));

restApi.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});

restApi.use('/api',rutas);
```

my managersocket.js:

```js
const io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('NUEVA CONEXION: ',socket.id);
    socket.emit('recoger',socket.id);
});

module.exports = io;
```

This is where I would like to use the socket or at least call the function.

and User.js:

```js
var io = require('../../socket/SocketManager');

var RouterUser = function(){

  this.practicafuncion = function (req,res){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    console.log('probando entrar por rest y que salga un mensaje por socket');
    res.send({
      status:'Aprobado',
      msj:'Enviado por rest'
    });
//this works correctly.     io.sockets.emit('mensaje','**MENSAJESERVIDORPORSOCKET**');
//This is not the problem when using "socket".   socket.broadcast.emit('mensaje','**MENSAJESERVIDORPORSOCKET**');
  };
}

module.exports = function(){
  var instancia = new RouterUser();
  return instancia;
};
```

same is the repository where the whole code is

```
https://github.com/proxirv/Socket.io-router
```

Answer (score 1):

`socket` is a temporary object that exists only for the duration of one particular client connection.  And, there can be zillions of them (one or more for each connected client).  As such, you don't just export one `socket` or stuff it in a global and try to use that everywhere.

So, if what you're trying to do is to access the socket.io connection for the user that you just received an http request for, that's a bit more complicated and there are several different ways to approach it.

One approach, I've used before is shown below:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(80);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const expsession = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');

// install session middleware
const sessionMiddleware = expsession({
  secret: 'random secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
});

// run session middleware for regular http connections
app.use(sessionMiddleware);

// run session middleware for socket.io connections
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});

// when a socket.io connection connects, put the socket.id into the session
// so it can be accessed from other http requests from that client    
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // socket.handshake.headers
    console.log(`socket.io connected: ${socket.id}`);

    // save socket.io socket in the session
    console.log("session at socket.io connection:\n", socket.request.session);
    socket.request.session.socketio = socket.id;
    socket.request.session.save();
});

// any arbitrary express route definition
// Note: you can't send socket.io data in a request that loads an HTML page
//       because that client hasn't yet established the socket.io connection
//       for that page.  The socket.io connections will be created after
//       the browser loads this page.
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    const session = req.session;
    console.log("\n\npage load\n---------------------------\n");
    console.log("session:\n", session);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "socket-io-session.html"));
});

// Upon an API call from a page that already has a socket.io connection,
// respond to the API call and send something to that page's socket.io socket
app.get("/api/test", function(req, res) {
    const session = req.session;
    io.sockets.connected[session.socketio].emit('show', "sending some data");
    console.log("session:\n", session);
    console.log("session.socketio:\n", session.socketio);
    res.json({greeting: "hello"});
});
```

Here are the steps in that concept:

1. Set up express-session for regular http connections.  This gives you a place to store stuff that belongs to one particular client (keyed by a cookie)
2. Set up express-session for the socket.io connection so you can also have access to express-session data in socket.io connections.
3. When a socket.io connection happens, store the socket.id in the sesssion.  This makes the socket.id available for future http requests from that specific client
4. When some future http request comes in from that client, you can reach into the session, get the socket.id value (which is just a string) and then use that to get the socket for that user and once you have the socket, you can use `socket.emit()` to send data just to that user.

---

If you didn't have other reasons for using express-session, you could also just put the socket.id into a cookie all by itself when the socket.io connection connects and then get the socket.id from the cookie during your http request.

Comment: First, thanks for giving me some of your time.
Your clarification is fine, but in my case I must follow this architecture, raise the io in a file other than index.js. raise io in a socketmanager.js file where your instance is located. In my index.js I make the call to a file where my routes are and in turn from there I call a function in a file called user.js that is where the logic will be. I need to be able to access io and socket from user.js, either using it there or calling functions that are inside of io in socketmanager.js

at the end of the post I put the repository address

Comment: @proxirv - Well, this is the architecture for middleware that makes the socket.io socket available in any Express request handler in any file for use by those request handlers.  How you split things across files is up to you.  This is a structure you can use.  If `io` is in a different file, then you just export `io` so you can use it in other files.  That's just a regular export/import design implementation.  This is the hard part of getting a user's socket.io connection available during an Express request handler for that user.  Not sure what else you're asking.

Comment: @proxirv - Did this answer your question? If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure. If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.